# SSRS ODAC Client TNS_Admin Configuration

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, tnsnames, odac, oracleclient

After installing ODAC client on server where SSRS is running, I'm wanting to move my TNSNames/SQLNET.ora config files to one centralized location. I've moved them to:

D:\apps\oracle_configs

And I've gone and set TNS_ADMIN to this directory in every conceivable location:

1. System Environment Variable
2. Registry
3. machine.config

For some reason, however, SSRS will not find the tnsnames.ora files at desired location. When trying to test connection to Oracle datasource in web report manager it will always fail with  error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

If I copy the files back to %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin directory and restart the SSRS service, the test connection succeeds.

What am I missing? How can I tell SSRS to look for TNS file at custom location and not the default Oracle Home dir?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to register the driver with the new path using **regsvr32**.

> 7. The same test connection, we will now be doing in SSRS. To do that we need to register the OraOLEDB driver. Go to the command Prompt (Run as Admin) -> and then run the following command. The path might vary as per your installation directory. We need to register the 64 bits driver since SSRS run on 64 bits (E:\app\client\xxxx\product\12.2.0\client_2\bin\OraOLEDB12.dll)

[MSDN: Configure Oracle data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/configure-oracle-data-source-for-sql-server-reporting-services-ssdt-and-report-server)

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/03/710.png))</sub>

Comment: Hmmm.. I wonder... So, I actually already did manually register that dll file as early troubleshooting step. At the time, it didn’t appear to change anything.. but now that you mention it, you’ve got me wondering...

Comment: @FernandoVega - Hope it helps - that's the only thing I could think of, though it's been over 5 years since I've had to use an Oracle db.

Comment: Nope, same error. Thanks for the thought though. I did update the TNS_ADMIN values in in regsitry, sys env var, and machine.config, after the fact. So, it was definitely worth a shot trying to register again. I just don't get it though... Other apps on this server appear to be working just fine with this config, just SSRS not liking it. 

I only went as far as machine.config for changing TNS_Admin value... Only thing that would supersede that would be app,config or web.config... But if I recall correctly, SSRS doesn't like it when people go touching her web.config.